# CGContext draw rotated rectangles

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am trying to draw rectangles that are separated by equal angles. To do this, I first draw a CGPath and then apply a transform to context. I do it  in succession 5 times. Here is my code and output. As you can see, output in screenshot is not correct, rectangles get skewed, not sure why. Need to know what I am doing wrong. And I believe I am doing an overkill, there might be a simpler way to achieve this. Please point me in the right direction.

```
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.setFillColor(UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.35).cgColor)

    let pathWidth = CGFloat(40)
    let pathHeight = CGFloat(20)

    context.saveGState()

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX - pathWidth/2, y: rect.midY - pathHeight/2, width: pathWidth, height: pathHeight))
    context.addPath(path)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)

    context.restoreGState()

    context.saveGState()
    let path2 = CGMutablePath()
    path2.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX - pathWidth/2, y: rect.midY - pathHeight/2, width: pathWidth, height: pathHeight))

    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height/2)
    context.rotate(by: -CGFloat.pi/20)
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -rect.height/2)
    context.addPath(path2)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    context.restoreGState()

    context.saveGState()
    let path3 = CGMutablePath()
    path3.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX - pathWidth/2, y: rect.midY - pathHeight/2, width: pathWidth, height: pathHeight))

    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height/2)
    context.rotate(by: -2*CGFloat.pi/20)
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -rect.height/2)

    context.addPath(path3)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    context.restoreGState()

    context.saveGState()
    let path4 = CGMutablePath()
    path4.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX - pathWidth/2, y: rect.midY - pathHeight/2, width: pathWidth, height: pathHeight))

    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height/2)
    context.rotate(by: -3*CGFloat.pi/20)
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -rect.height/2)

    context.addPath(path4)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    context.restoreGState()

    context.saveGState()
    let path5 = CGMutablePath()
    path5.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX - pathWidth/2, y: rect.midY - pathHeight/2, width: pathWidth, height: pathHeight))

    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height/2)
    context.rotate(by: -4*CGFloat.pi/20)
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -rect.height/2)

    context.addPath(path5)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    context.restoreGState()


    context.saveGState()
    let path6 = CGMutablePath()
    path4.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX - 10, y: rect.midY - 0.5, width: 20, height: 1))

    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height/2)
    context.rotate(by: -5*CGFloat.pi/20)
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -rect.height/2)

    context.addPath(path6)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    context.restoreGState()

}
```

This is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Why are you changing the rotation angle if you want your rectangles to be rotated by the same angle?

Comment: I want the successive rectangles to be separated by angle Pi/20, how do I do that. I am going to make an edit to the question as I got some success, but not not full.

Comment: You should simply call `context.rotate(by: -CGFloat.pi/20)` each time, don't multiply the angle between each rotation.

Comment: The center of rectangle is outside the rectangle. It is (0, superview.bounds.height/2). Are you sure only context.rotate will work? Around which point will the rotation be applied?

Comment: And I somehow believe I am doing an overkill by repeatedly saving and restoring Graphics State and applying a transform to rectangle. Besides the rectangles get skewed.

Comment: "trying to draw rectangles that are separated by equal angles ... [but] rectangles get skewed”. I don’t understand the question. The rectangles are rotated, but not skewed. I’m not understanding what you’re trying to achieve...

Comment: @Rob Carefully look at rectangle number 2 & 3 from the bottom, the widths of the opposite sides do not look same.

Comment: I might suggest that this is an optical illusion. I believe they really are rectangular (e.g., if you remove/obscure everything else except for that one block, doesn’t appear to be skewed, as it does when positioned so close to the other rectangles).

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code, which should have no skewed.

```
          var myLayer: CGLayer!
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.setFillColor(UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.35).cgColor)

    let pathWidth = CGFloat(40)
    let pathHeight = CGFloat(20)

     myLayer = CGLayer.init(context, size: CGSize.init(width: pathWidth, height: pathHeight), auxiliaryInfo: nil)
    let contex = myLayer.context
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pathWidth, height: pathHeight))
    contex?.addPath(path)
     contex?.setFillColor(UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.35).cgColor)
    contex?.drawPath(using: .fill)


   (0...6).forEach
    {
   context.saveGState()

   context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height/2)
   context.rotate(by: -CGFloat.pi * CGFloat($0) / 20)
   context.draw(myLayer!, at: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: -pathHeight / 2))

   context.restoreGState()
    }
```

a more precise result is shown as following:

```
  (0...6).forEach
    {
   context.saveGState()

        let angle = CGFloat.pi * -CGFloat($0) / 20

        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height/2 + pathHeight/2 + (rect.width + pathWidth)/2 * sin (angle))
        context.translateBy(x: (rect.width + pathWidth)/2 * cos(angle)  , y: 0)

        context.rotate(by:angle)
        context.translateBy(x:  -pathWidth/2, y: -pathHeight / 2)

        context.draw(myLayer!, at: CGPoint.zero)



   context.restoreGState()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Output looks almost same as the one I posted in the image attached to the question. Somehow I feel that rectangles number 2, 3, 5 are not perfect rectangles -- the opposite sides do not look to be of same length. Is it an optical illusion or a reality?